# Trouble solving a second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've solved some first-order equations and now, in physics, I came across such an equation for the harmonic motion.

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\omega^2x$

How can I find all functions $x = f(t)$ satisfying this equation? I tried the usual first-order methods, but I failed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming, as you state, that you can solve first degree equations, here is a way of converting one second degree equation into two first degree ones.

Note that:

$$x''-i\omega x'=-i\omega x'-\omega^2 x$$ so setting $y=x'-i\omega x$ this gives the linear equation $y'=-i\omega y$ with the solution $y=Ae^{-i\omega t}$

Also note:$$x''+i\omega x'=i\omega x'-\omega^2 x$$ and set $z=x'+i\omega x$ to obtain $z'=i\omega z$ and $z=Be^{i\omega t}$

Then note that $$z-y=2i\omega x = Be^{i\omega t}-Ae^{-i\omega t}$$

Incorporating $2i\omega$ into the constants this gives $$x=Ce^{i\omega t}+De^{-i\omega t}=E\sin \omega t+F\cos \omega t$$

(the last formulation arises from the formulae for sin and cos in terms of complex exponentials)

---

Note that in general the second degree equation $$x''=(a+b)x'-abx$$ can be rewritten as $$x''-ax'=bx'-abx$$ and $$x''-bx'=ax'-abx$$

and the same technique can be applied. This does not work when $a=b$ (you get one linear equation repeated twice) and you might want to investigate this possibility further.

Comment: And the idea to add $\pm i \omega x'$ comes from the general remark, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation $r^2=-\omega^2$ has the roots $r=\pm i\omega$ so the solutions of the ODE is

$$x(t)=a\cos(\omega t)+b\sin(\omega t)$$

Comment: I'd appreciate your consideration: [undelete?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974974/algebraic-word-problems/974990#974990)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\omega^2x$$ Substitute $$\frac{dx}{dt}=y$$ then $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} =\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y\dfrac{dy}{dx}.$$ Hence $$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\omega^2x.$$ I think you can solve this separable first order equation for $y.$ Then use it for obtaining $x$ in terms of $t.$

**EDIT:** Suppose when $x=a,$ we have  $y=0.$ Then $$y^2=\omega^2(a^2-x^2)$$ $$y=\omega\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$ Her I omitted the $-$ sign of square root. If you want you can add it to your calculations. Now $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\omega\sqrt{a^2-x^2}.$$ Again a separable first order differential equation.
CASE $1:$ $a\not=0$ $$\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\omega dt$$ $$\arcsin \dfrac{x}{a}=\omega t+b$$  $$x=a\sin(\omega t+b)$$

CASE $2:$ $a=0$ $$\dfrac{dx}{x}=i\omega dt$$ $$\ln x=i\omega t+\ln b$$  $$x=be^{i\omega t}$$

More generally, Always you have a solution of the form $$x=A\sin \omega t+B\cos \omega t.$$

Comment: And why can I write $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ as if the derivative were a ratio?

Comment: It is called the chain rule. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FChain_rule&ei=X0yhVPi5Jsi1uQTawYC4CQ&usg=AFQjCNEiGGMTSMFlvrpTyZ4gpVmFiifjwA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E&cad=rja

Comment: Well, I got $$y^2 = -\omega^2 x^2 + c_0\\$$ so $$y = -i\omega x + c_1$$. And now I have trouble with getting a right solution, because after $$ \frac { \frac {dx}{dt} } {i\omega x + c_1} = 1$$ and integrating wrt $t$ I won't even get two $e^\phi$ words

Comment: Look at my edited answer. Note that $$\sqrt{a+b}\not=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}.$$

Comment: It is not, I know ;) But $c_0 \neq c_1$, so I can always find such a constant, in this case $$ {c_1} = \sqrt{-\omega^2 x^2 + c_0} - \sqrt{-\omega^2 x^2}$$

Comment: Here $c_1$ is not a constant. It depends on $x.$

Comment: Yes, indeed ;) Tried to be too smart :) Thanks

Comment: After solving $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\omega\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$ I get $$\pm i \omega t = arcsin \frac x a + b$$, so $$x = a sin(\pm i\omega t + b)$$ and it's not the expected formula

Comment: If $$y^2 = -\omega^2 x^2$$ (omitting the constant now) then $$y = i\omega x \vee y = -i \omega x $$ because there are two roots of such equation in complex numbers

Comment: See my edited answer.